# Running grunt from Jenkins as `root` user

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, root

I need Jenkins to execute some shell commands every time someone makes a push. One of them is `grunt prod` but it's only working if i execute it as the `root` user. If i try to use it as `jenkins` user i get the following:

`[4mRunning "ngAnnotate:production" (ngAnnotate) task[24m`
`[33mWarning: Unable to write "public/dist/application.js" file (Error code:` `EACCES).` `Use --force to continue.[39m`

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add your jenkins user say `jenkins` to `/etc/sudoers` and allow it to execute `sudo` without asking for password by:

`jenkins    ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/sh, /path/to/your/script`

Then you can use `sudo` to run the script:

`sudo /path/to/your/script`

If you must execute with the user `root`, I think first you should allow `root` to login via `SSH`, then use Jenkins SSH plugin to login as `root` and execute your script.

Hope it helps.